# MySQL string replace

Tags: mysql, regex, replace, preg-replace

Hey, what's the most effective way to remove beginning and ending slashes from all rows in a particular column using MySQL?

**Before:**

```
/hello/world/
foo/bar/
/something/else
/one/more/*
```

**After:**

```
hello/world
foo/bar
something/else
one/more/*
```

...or maybe this should be done in PHP instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [TRIM()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET my_field=TRIM(BOTH '/' FROM my_field);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could definitelyt make this work using the [MySQL string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) but I think this would be best handled outside of the database using PHP or whatever programming language of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP option: (I'm assuming the fetched row is in `$row`)

```
$row['Field'] = explode('/', $row['Field']);
//Remove the empty elements
$row['Field'] = array_filter($row['Field']);
$row['Field'] = implode('/', $row['Field']);
```

Comment: No need for array. $row['Field'] = trim($row['Field'], '/'); should do the trick.